# How to see change brought on by a commit?

Tags: git

We have a GitBlit server, but if I log in, the UI doesn't really show me the change brought on by n commit. I was hoping there is some command like "git commit [HASH]" that shows you the change that was made by that commit.

Is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: Sandeep's answer (`git show`) is usually the one you want. Note that `git show` actually runs `git diff` (well, more precisely, a slight variant of it). `git diff` will let you compare *any* commit to *any other* commit, but only two commits at a time in general; or one commit vs your work-tree, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

`git show <commit-id>`

It will show you the commit message and the diff.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff HEAD^` will show you the diff between current and last commit

`git diff <HASH>` will show you the diff between current and any commit

you can also use HEAD~3 to just go back 3 commits etc